# cycles material for marshmallow "peeps"

Tags: texturing, materials

Does anyone have ideas for this material? Especially the sugar on the surface which I'd like to model as small cubes rather than rounded bumps as in Voronoi? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Cycles render engine you could probably achieve a simplistic setup quickly using a mix between a diffuse and a translucent shader node. A voronoi texture for displacement or bump could help with the rough surface.

[image: Peep Marshmallow shader]

My diffuse color was setup for a quick random colors for display purposes, but you can use any solid color instead by removing the *ColorRamp* node and the *Object Info* radom output

Comment: Kinda looks as if it's a render with low samples. But i feel it's the right direction.

Comment: It is in a way, it was just captured from the viewport preview, not a lot of samples were used. But you can then adjust the scale/intensity of the bump or displacement to your liking, or eliminate it all along if you dislike the effect.

Comment: One more thing, you could change the voronoi type from "Intensity" to "Cells" if you want a more "angular" type of bump instead.

Comment: Ah, see. Personally i'd feel as if Cells may look better, and i'd personally choose that.

Comment: @Duarte That looks way better than I got when I tried it! Thank you.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos why did you use a divide node instead of just changing the scale of the texture to 10?

Comment: The divide node where it stands affects the intensity or strength of the bump, not it's scale