# cycles material -- change color based on position

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-coordinates

I'm (ultimately) trying to make a big static group of people using the hair particle system, and the same mesh is (obviously) being repeated (and random sizing is great using hair particles), but I want their clothes to change color based on where they are (a.k.a., for each of them to have a different colored shirt etc.)

I was thinking about going about this (WITh using only 1 mesh) by somehow making a big colorful noise texture and have the color in the cycles material choose a point in that big noise texture, so that depending on the position, the color will change.

I know a similar thing can be done with the displacement modifier using global coordinates (and obviously the result being a different DISPLACEMENT), but I'm not exactly how to do a similar thing with nodes to the color of a cycles material.

Anyone>?

Comment: You *can* use position property as input for a material, but wouldn't [true random colors](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46774/cycles-random-material-with-alpha-texture) be [much more appropriate](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52307/cycles-material-for-marshmallow-peeps/52316#52316)?

Comment: Also related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70255/generate-particles-with-random-colors-continuously-or-from-a-set and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dHVoDGDrWEw

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos just tried that random method and it's really good

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos but how would I do it based on 3d position? (and with a picture for instance)